# Content inside WPF button getting focus on tabbing

Tags: c#, wpf

When we operate the application through keyboard tab, the content inside the button "Next" is also getting the tab.

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Name="HideWelcomePageButton"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.IsEnabled}" MinWidth="100"
                Command="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.ButtonCommand}" Margin="30 0 0 0"
                Content="Next">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Is there any setting by which we can disable the focus and tab stop on the content inside button. It should be only on the button.

Comment: `<Button Focusable="False".../>`

Comment: Do you have a custom button template in your application? The default WPF template only focuses the button and not the content of the button.

Comment: Are you talking just about the dotted line in your screenshot?

Comment: The default WPF template does not focus only the button. It also focuses the text inside the button.

Comment: @BradleyUffner i added the screenshot just to show that the text inside the button is also getting focus, which i dont want

Comment: I solved the problem by setting KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation ="None" on the button control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the property **KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation ="None"** as follows

```
<Button KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation ="None" Content="{Binding NoButtonText}">
```

By making this change, only the button is getting focus on tabbing, not the text inside the button.

Answer (score 2):

To make the button focusable but not the text inside it, you can don't set a default `Content` attribute value and set a Label/TextBlock inside the Button XAML tag, and declare it as not focusable.

```
<Button Name="HideWelcomePageButton"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.IsVisible, 
            Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.IsEnabled}" 
            MinWidth="100"
            Command="{Binding Path=HideWelcomePageButton.ButtonCommand}" 
            Margin="30 0 0 0">
<Label Focusable="false">Next</Label>
</Button>
```

By other hand, if you want only to disable the border of the button's text focus, add the attribute :

`FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` to your button Control.

To re-enable it, set that attribute to a Style of your choice.

[Source](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/41906)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, after doing this also, the text in the button was getting selected on tabbing

Comment: @Richa Garg it works for me, can you share your XAML? I updated the answer

Comment: I added the property KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation = "None" for the button